# What is the name for [x for x in some_list] type of construct in python?

Tags: python

Couldn't really find it, but probably it's me not knowing how to search properly :(

Just wanted to find out what the name is for:

```
[x for x in some_list]
```

type of construct?

Comment: Here, Google really is your friend:  searching for '"x for x in list" python' gives us the Effbot as the first hit!  http://effbot.org/zone/python-list.htm

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)